# Copy weights from one bone and invert it?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

So I have this one human model which seems to be made by making half of the body and then duplicating it and flipping it to give it the other half, I'm wondering if it would be possible for me to let's say, rig the left leg, could I somehow copy the weight from that and invert them to the right leg? Same for hands, etc?